# What is the easiest way to design this room setup? 3D but not 3D

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, 3d

[image]

I can do this in Cinema 4D but it will take a lot of time, looking for an alternative software that creates 3D looks like a 2D scene in real quick.

Comment: Quick means youd have assets ready made.

Comment: @joojaa nope, everything from scratch.

Comment: then No, drawing it is no faster than modeling. Just dependent on your skill.

Comment: A classic pixel drawing, so use PS. Create the elements like tiles and arrange them layered from  back to front. Don't draw the same thing twice, just copy/paste and layer properly.

Comment: Judging by the style, this is [Habbo Hotel](https://www.habbo.com/), and you van make environments like these inside that game / social medium.

Comment: Be warned though that all you create will be copyrighted by Habbo. Using it in anything beyond personal use will be copyright infringement. Since Habbo is a big company aimed at adolescents, I suspect they will have a keen-eyed legal department.

Comment: @Vincent please don't answer in comments :P ((runs and hides))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @AAGD suggested, this is a hand-drawn raster image. It wasn't made in any 3D software.

You can create the same in nearly any type of raster image software with a brush/pencil tool that supports drawing without any softening, for that aliased edge look, typically referred to as pixel art. PhotoShop, the most well known, can do this with its pencil tool.

These days there's a lot of dedicated software for drawing pixel art. There's actually so many that I'd suggest Googling for them rather than me listing any here. They provide a reduced and refined set of tools dedictated to pixel drawing and typically show their strengths with animation tools specifically geared towards pixel art. Ultimately, a good ability to illustrate is fundamental to using any. Whichever you use is just personal preference.

As with lots of illustrations and paintings, the artist used their understanding of what an isometric 3d view would look like at a chosen angle - intuition and observation, basically - rather than any sort of 3d tools.

In terms of the easiest approach: once the artist had the basics drawn in one area, they were able to copy lots of the scene into other areas. Besides the obvious duplication of pixels for various desks, chairs and pillars, a lot of the walls are repeated and these would have been copied too.

I'll also add that a lot of people aren't aware of using the pencil tool in PhotoShop in conjunction with the shift key. This is pretty essential for pixel art. With the shift key held, you can force straight lines at 90 degree angles. Secondly, if you click one point, hold shift and click another point, PhotoShop automatically draws a straight pixel line between both points, at any angle. Once you have base lines set up at the angles you'll be using throughout the image, you can copy them elsewhere to extend and add new lines. It's a very rapid way of sketching out a scene while retaining the same angle for lines.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool out there called MagicaVoxel which is open-source and free, allowing voxel based world and image building which I think would make this kind of image *really* fast to do.

[link to MagicaVoxel github page](https://ephtracy.github.io/)

I've played with it a bit (I'm a 3D generalist) and it's low-barrier and fun enough that I think a hobbyist could learn it quickly.

Comment: Hello GerardFalla, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!